# Вопросы уровня "Домашнее задание"

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Уже несколько раз обсуждалось, что формулировка и сама процедура этого основания для закрытия темы порождает лишние вопросы и недоразумения. Но я немного в другом свете эту проблему вижу, поэтому отдельной темой.

Проблема эта, на мой взгляд, в том, что новички воспринимают ресурс как некий бесплатный сервис выполнения домашних заданий или, того хуже, как исполнителя их профессиональных обязанностей. Последнее время, если я правильно оценил обстановку, такие гости стали являться много чаще - и это уже реально раздражает.

Вот условный пример такого вопроса: <<*Какой знак должен стоять вместо подчеркивания: "Сделал дело_гуляй смело">>? Такая постановка вопроса заставляет думать, что автор просто не открывал учебник класса этак пятого-шестого и не знает, какие вообще пунктуационные знаки существуют.

Полагаю, надо:
1. помещать причину для закрытия в комментарий - сразу и всегда (сейчас это делается, только если предложение по закрытию сделано из очереди проверок или закрытие уже состоялось - по факту).
2. Саму формулировку дополнить или изменить так, чтобы не было повадно препираться насчет того, что это не домашнее задание. Я бы написал так-то так: 
***Мы не выполняем домашних заданий и не отвечаем на вопросы элементарного уровня, если спрашивающий не дал свое решение и не обозначил конкретную причину своих затруднений.*** 
Обсуждаемо, но что-то делать надо.